# How do you choose a diode for a 5v to 3.3v clamping circuit

Tags: diodes, components, converter, component-selection, logic-level

I have a logic input that is 3.3v and I want to be able to allow it to interface with either 3.3v or 5v input signals w/o worrying about it being damaged.  I would like to use a resistor with a clamping diode but I'm unsure how to choose an appropriate diode or even what specific type of diode is the right one to use.

What are the relevant specifications I should look for when choosing a diode to clamp an input signal to 3.3v?

Comment: Why not use a series diode with a pull-up?

Comment: This particular signal needs to default to low for safety reasons so it has to have a pull down resistor which wouldn't work with a series diode as I understand it.

Comment: Or a series led with pull down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more reading I think I found the answer.  What I'm asking about might also be described as a "clipping" circuit.  [The Wikipedia article on clipping circuits has a good explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(electronics)) of how the parameters of a diode affect the clipping.

The important parameter when choosing a diode for a clamping / clipping circuit is the forward voltage Vf.  The voltage will be clipped to Vf + what ever the reference voltage is on the diodes cathode.  So generally speaking you are going to want to choose a diode with a very low forward voltage so that the clipping is as close to the ideal value as possible.  Schottky diodes typically have very low forward voltages.

Answer (score 2):

Use a diode that is fast enough to handle the voltage changes on the line.
Check for the current that will flow though the diode and make sure it can handle that.

Simply, a Schottky diode with a rating of 50mA to 100mA should suffice.

Alternatively, use a voltage divider with a division ratio of:
5V/3.3V = 1.51

It will also work for 3.3V:
3.3V/1.51 = 2.18V

Because 2.18V is above the minimum voltage level for logic 1.

Comment: "Because 2.18V is above the minimum voltage level for logic 1." Just barely.

Comment: Or just use a series resistor and let the protection diodes of the GPIO (if there are any) handle the over-voltage. ;)